# cartridges in openshift origin web console

Tags: centos, openshift-origin

I'm trying to install openshift origin, i already have the "broker" and one node fully configured and in the node i installed a few cartridges that were in the repositories.

Then i imported and activated the cartridges with the command:

```
oo-admin-ctl-cartridge -c import-node --activate
```

and the output says that is all ok, and next i cleaned the console's cache with:

```
oo-admin-console-cache -c
```

Then i rebooted the openshift-broker and httpd services, but the web console doesn't show any cartridges, only the quickstarts app

Here is the output of oo-admin-ctl-cartridges -c list

```
[root@broker]# oo-admin-ctl-cartridge -c list
  cron-1.4       plugin    Cron 1.4           2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  mongodb-2.4    service   MongoDB 2.4        2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  mysql-5.1      service   MySQL 5.1          2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  mysql-5.5      service   MySQL 5.5          2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  phpmyadmin-4   service   phpMyAdmin 4.0     2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  postgresql-8.4 service   PostgreSQL 8.4     2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  postgresql-9.2 service   PostgreSQL 9.2     2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  switchyard-0   service   SwitchYard 0.8.0   2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  diy-0.1        web       Do-It-Yourself 0.1 2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  jenkins-1      web       Jenkins Server     2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  mock-0.1       web       Mock Cartridge 0.1 2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  mock-0.2       web       Mock Cartridge 0.2 2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  mock-0.3       web       Mock Cartridge 0.3 2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  mock-0.4       web       Mock Cartridge 0.4 2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  nodejs-0.10    web       Node.js 0.10       2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  nodejs-0.6     web       Node.js 0.6        2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  perl-5.10      web       Perl 5.10          2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  php-5.3        web       PHP 5.3            2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  php-5.4        web       PHP 5.4            2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  python-2.6     web       Python 2.6         2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  python-2.7     web       Python 2.7         2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  python-3.3     web       Python 3.3         2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  ruby-1.8       web       Ruby 1.8           2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  ruby-1.9       web       Ruby 1.9           2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
  haproxy-1.4    web_proxy Web Load Balancer  2015/01/30 19:54:09 UTC
```

I had to copy the directory /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/ and its contents from the node host because the broker host doesn't had it, but nothing happened.

What can i do?